# Can I force a legend entry, even for dataless series?

Tags: gnuplot

My Gnuplot 4.4 is plotting data from *N* files, each of which has an unknown number of *NaNs* (which won't be plotted). I've used the following "trick" to make all of the data appear to be part of the same data series:

```
plot  "fileA.dat" using 1:2 linecolor rgbcolor #FF0000 title 'My data', \
      "fileB.dat" using 1:2 linecolor rgbcolor #FF0000, \
      "fileC.dat" using 1:2 linecolor rgbcolor #FF0000
```

Notice that the colours are the same, and the title is only given for the first file.

But, if `fileA.dat` has only NaNs (or for any other reason does not contain plottable information), the series is omitted and I don't get a title at all.

Can I make fileA.dat's legend entry show up regardless, or is there perhaps a better approach to "sharing" legend entries across series? Assume that I do not have any more information than already declared here, before invoking `plot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the title on an "invisible function" like this:

```
plot  "fileA.dat" using 1:2 linecolor rgbcolor "#FF0000" notitle, \
      "fileB.dat" using 1:2 linecolor rgbcolor "#FF0000" notitle, \
      "fileC.dat" using 1:2 linecolor rgbcolor "#FF0000" notitle, \
      NaN linecolor rgbcolor "#FF0000" title "My data"
```

The linestyle of the explicit "NaN" can also be modified.

Comment: Genius. :) Never occurred to me to try this, seeing as a "file" input with only NaNs obliterated the title for that series. How odd!

Comment: Crucially, I can have as many "dummy" series as I like, so this scales really well with multiple (_N_) logical datasets (over _N_ \* _M_ files).